# Add a SVG object on a timescale axis in D3?

Tags: d3.js

I am trying to overlay a SVG rect object on a D3 line chart that I currently have.  The x axis of the chart is a timescale and I'm having a hard time trying to set the starting x coordinate on a specific date on the timescale.  What is the best way to do this?

```
  svg.append("rect")
   .attr("x", )  // start x on 20130301
   .attr("y", height)
   .attr("width", 50)
   .attr("height", height)
   .attr("fill", "red");
```

Existing code:

```
var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 50},
    width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var parseDate = d3.time.format("%Y%m%d").parse;

var x = d3.time.scale()
    .range([0, width]);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([height, 0]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("bottom");

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient("left");

var area = d3.svg.area()
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.Date); })
    .y0(height)
    .y1(function(d) { return y(d.Close); });

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

d3.json('JSONstockPriceOverTime.php', function (error, data) {
  data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.Date = parseDate(d.Date);
    d.Close = +d.Close;
  });

x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.Date; }));
y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.Close; })]);

svg.append("path")
  .datum(data)
  .attr("class", "area")
  .attr("d", area);

svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "x axis")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
  .call(xAxis);

svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "y axis")
  .call(yAxis)
.append("text")
  .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
  .attr("y", 6)
  .attr("dy", ".71em")
  .style("text-anchor", "end")
  .text("Price ($)");
});
```

Answer (score 3):

It might be worth setting up a fiddle (jsfiddle.net) to help speed this along, but at an eyeball, try:

```
var myDate = new Date();
myDate.setYear( 2013 );  // .setMonth , .setDate
svg.append("rect")
  .attr("x", x( myDate ) )  // start x on 20130301
```

This says to use your x-scale to compute the output based on the date input. The x-scale is a function mapping the domain (dates) to range (pixel value)

Comment: Be sure to mark the question as answered (check mark) to improve your profile rating and help other people know that this helped.